# Java - cannot find symbol - constructor

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a method from another class called Digits but referring to it in a class called FourDigits. I've tried to create an instance variable by using the following code:

```
public class FourDigits


private Digits TwoDigitA;
private Digits TwoDigitB;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class FourDigits
 */
public FourDigits()
{
    TwoDigitA = new Digits();
    TwoDigitB = new Digits();
    setValues();
    setIncrement();
    getDisplayString();
}
```

The first class, Digits:

```
public class Digits

private int value;
private int tooHigh;
private String displayString;


public Digits(int anyNum)
{
    value = 0;
    tooHigh=anyNum;
    displayString = "";
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok first, your class doesn't have { brackets.. don't know if this is a copy/paste error but well..

and second your constructor needs a int parameter

```
TwoDigitA = new Digits();
```

you don't specify an int here..

```
TwoDigitA = new Digits(12);
```

or remove the anyNum from

```
public Digits(int anyNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Digits constructor requires a parameter. Digits() doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Digits constructor takes an integer in your code... you don't give it any integers when you make the "twodigits" and it doesn't have a constructor with no arguments...